# Layout to create desktop application in javafx

Tags: javafx, fxml

I want to know that what is the best layout i can use in javafx that could make the components look and position the same in every resolution? For example I am using gridpane in fxml, will it be okay for different resolutions?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What are you trying to do? Do you mean different screen resolutions?

Comment: i simply don't want my components to change their position or size when i run my application on a different resolution.